# better way to stop program execution after certain time

Tags: c++, time

I have following which stop execution of program after certain time.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include<ctime>
using namespace std; 

int main( )
{ 
    time_t timer1;
    time(&timer1);
    time_t  timer2;
    double second;
    while(1)
    {
        time(&timer2);
        second = difftime(timer2,timer1);
        //check if timediff is cross 3 seconds
        if(second > 3)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is above program would work if time increase from 23:59 to 00:01 ?

If there any other better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`time()` returns the time since the Epoch (00:00:00 UTC, January 1, 1970), measured in seconds. Thus, the time of day does not matter.

Comment: as I getting time in while loop `time(&timer2);` is memory allocated to `timer2` freed by system itself?

Comment: Yes, after `main()` returns.

Answer (score 2):

Provided you have C++11, you can have a look at [this example:](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/this_thread/sleep_for/)

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono> 
int main() {
  std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::seconds(3));
  return 0;
}
```

Alternatively I'd go with a threading library of your choice and use its Thread sleep function. In most cases it is better to send your thread to sleep instead of busy waiting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`std::chrono::steady_clock`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/steady_clock/) in C++11. Check the example in the [`now` static method](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/steady_clock/now/) for an example :

```
  using namespace std::chrono;

  steady_clock::time_point clock_begin = steady_clock::now();

  std::cout << "printing out 1000 stars...\n";
  for (int i=0; i<1000; ++i) std::cout << "*";
  std::cout << std::endl;

  steady_clock::time_point clock_end = steady_clock::now();

  steady_clock::duration time_span = clock_end - clock_begin;
  double nseconds = double(time_span.count()) * steady_clock::period::num / steady_clock::period::den;

  std::cout << "It took me " << nseconds << " seconds.";
  std::cout << std::endl;
```